# Adding Stylesheet in Wordpress for a plugin, not a theme

Tags: wordpress

in the index.php of a custom plugin i have put this :

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style_overview', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'http://127.0.0.1/wp-content/plugins/profile_plugin/css/style_overview.css',false,'1.1','all');
```

But it returns this in the final head :

```
href="http://127.0.0.1/wp-content/themes/alchemistshttp://127.0.0.1/wp-content/plugins/profile_plugin/css/style_overview.css?ver=1.1"
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining this path in the enqueue style function. With the dot . you are connecting with the following string.

You can use this to get the current plugins url:

```
plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/css/style_overview.css'
```

Or you can just define it hard coded as you did:

```
'style_overview', 'http://127.0.0.1/wp-content/plugins/profile_plugin/css/style_overview.css'
```

The function you are using gives you the url where the style.css of your active theme is located:

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
```

That is why you are getting your theme path followed by the url you added as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `plugins_url()` and then append your directory or file structure on the end of that.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/

Example:

```
wp_register_style(
    'my-css',
    plugins_url( '/blocks/dist/style.css', __FILE__ ),
    array( 'wp-blocks' )
);
```